# SwiftUI Preview: move canvas while zoomed in

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, preview

I'm debugging layout in SwiftUI canvas and would like to zoom it in 400%, so that I can evaluate the alignment perfectly.

I use the +/- icons in order to zoom in, but when I try to either click & move the canvas or scroll with 2 fingers (using the trackpad), nothing happens.

I'd like to move to other parts of the iPhone Preview, so that I can inspect the layout details.

**Screenshot Zoomed In**
[image]

**I'd like to get here:**
[image]

Code:

```
struct ProductCart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Range(1...5)) { value in
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: .halfPadding) {
                    Text(String(repeating: "Save on the newest iPhone with the latest carrier deals. Directly from Apple.",
                                count: value))
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13 - scrolled with mouse

Comment: yeah, just checked, it works in 13 beta. I'm on 12 unfortunately.
Please, answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I checked on 12.5 and it is working as well. One thing to note, you didn't give us `.halfPadding` so I used a constant. Could that be the issue? Else, I would restart and see if that clears it out.

Comment: Not really,  that shouldn't be an issue... It definitely works for 13, but I tried to move in 12.5.1 and cannot do so...